# iPad Replace Segue -- Could not find a split view controller ancestor

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, segue

I've connected a bunch of navigation controllers to my UISplitViewController to replace the detail view, however when I do I get this error

```
'Could not find a split view controller ancestor for '<UISplitViewController: 0x6a52f50>',
while performing a split view controller replace segue (identifier 'Queue') with
destination '<UINavigationController: 0x6870ff0>''
```

And I can usually guess what's going on from these internal inconsistencies but this one I literally have no idea -- any help is much appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Examine the sequence of segues leading into the source scene. If it doesn't contain a split view controller in the mix, you've found your problem. Replace segues can only be used in scenes that are presented in the context of a split view controller.

Comment: retainCount, what do you mean by that? I have a UITVC calling another UITVC which calls a UISplitViewController. It is when I try to call the UISVC that it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue and all my segues were fine, no code was interfering. Turns out the problem was in the master view controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UISplitViewController *splitViewController;
```

The property had become unused and something was trying to use it while it was `nil`. Simply removing it did the trick.